# What is pixel.facebook.com do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cross-domain

I came across this site  pixel.facebook.com , and I found that if we log via facebook.com it will go through pixel.facebook.com for micro period of time . Can anyone have an idea what is pixel.facebook.com and why its share the session cross domain ?

Comment: They serve tracking pixels from that domain. https://www.facebook.com/help/236257763148568

Comment: It's not about the thing on the link

Comment: Pixels allow fb to read any existing Facebook cookies or also place a new cookie on your browser or device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixels allow fb to read any existing Facebook cookies or also place a new cookie on your browser or device.